# Proof by induction: form of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, induction

Problem: Any polynomial $P_n(x)$ can be written as $P_n(x)$=$\sum_{i=0}^n c_i \alpha_i(x) $ where $\alpha_i(x)$ is a polynomial of degree exactly $i$.

Attempt: Base case ($n=1$): $P_1(x)=c_0+c_1(x)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^1 c_i \alpha_i(x)= c_0+c_1(x)$.

Inductive hypothesis: Suppose this holds for $(n)$, and show that it holds for $(n+1)$. (Show that $P_{n+1}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} c_i \alpha_i(x)$ using that $P_n(x)$=$\sum_{i=0}^n c_i \alpha_i(x)$)

Here's where I get confused; I don't quite understand the argument.

Comment: The key is to assume that $P_n(x)$ is true (your induction hypothesis). Then you can use that to show $P_{n+1}(x)$ is true.

Comment: Yes I know this is something easy,but the argument confuses me; I'm not sure how to use $P_n(x)$ to show $P_{n+1}(x)$

Comment: I'm not sure either, so I will comment instead of answer. I tried to express your $P_{n+1}$ as $$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}c_i \alpha_i(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i \alpha_i(x)+c_{n+1}(x)\alpha_{n+1}(x).$$ We know that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i \alpha_i(x)$ and $c_{n+1}(x)\alpha_{n+1}(x)$ are both polynomials. The addition of two polynomials yields another polynomial.

Comment: By the way, $c_{n+1}(x)\alpha_{n+1}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$, based on the definition you have. The term $\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i \alpha_i(x)$ is a summation of all polynomials up to degree $n$, which is the highest degree. In other words, the entire summation is a polynomial itself up to degree $n$. So the first term is a polynomial as well.

Comment: You need to either assume that the $\,\alpha_i\,$ are all monic (lead coef $=1)\,$ or that the lead coef's are all units (invertibles), e.g. if the coefficient ring is a field. Is it?

Comment: Thank you,it doesn't seem like much of a proof but I think that's it. thanks dragon,this is very helpful!

Comment: @user1961722 You're welcome. I didn't intend to write a proof; I just wanted to spout some ideas (hence, comments instead of an answer). Hopefully you're able to fashion a neat proof, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,\deg P = n\,$ and $P$ has lead coef $\,p\,$ and $\,\alpha_n\,$ has lead coef $\,a\,$ then $\,P' = P - p/a\,\alpha_n$ has degree $< n$ since the lead terms cancel. So, by induction, $\, P' = c_1\alpha_1 + \cdots+ c_{n-1} \alpha_{n-1}\,$ thus $\,P = P' + p/a\,\alpha_n\,$  yields the sought form for $\,P.$

**Remark** $ $ We are essentially using the Polynomial Division Algorithm to divide $\,P\,$ by $\,\alpha_n\,\,$ so $\, P = q\, \alpha_n + r,\,$ but in the special case where the quotient $\,q\,$ is always a constant polynomial, since the divisor and dividend have equal degrees.